# Generate event on hover by selected image

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

Is there any code for hover? i mean if i select an image which is draggable and when this image put over another image, it generate an alert?

please reply, thanks

Comment: That is not `hover`, that should be something like `dragover`.

Comment: HMTL5 Drag & Drop tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: actually i want to grab some fruits which are dropping from a tree by a basket, fruits are dropping and i have a draggable basket to catch. what i want to do is when fruits are dropping after hover my draggable image it disappear. here is [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qC3WY/2/).select the logo, and suppose ball is moving by animation and when i hover it by image, ball get disappear.

Comment: please have a look, http://jsfiddle.net/qC3WY/2/

Comment: please have a look at my answer,I think it's what you need, if not, try to explain better what do you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zL3mp/2/

This is the code used... very basic but working

```
var divTwoPosition = $('#two').position();
$('#one').draggable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        // get distances
        var x = $('#one').position().left;
        var y = $('#one').position().top;
        // adjust to threshold of position coordinates
        var x_min = divTwoPosition.left - 180;
        var x_max = divTwoPosition.left + 180;
        var y_min = divTwoPosition.top - 100;
        var y_max = divTwoPosition.top + 100;
        if ((x >= x_min && x <= x_max) && (y >= y_min && y <= y_max)) alert("It is over");
    }
});
```

I think this is exactly what you need. adjust the threshold ints to fit your image width + height.

In this case Width = 180 and Height = 100, so if draggable div touches static div, it will display an alert :)

Comment: yes that is some sort of, i am trying to put into my code, also its not working in mozilla, works on other. thanks

Comment: You can try using `.offset()` instead of `.position()` as the one I used in my example is relative to it's offset parent, and offset is relative to the document, in my case, parent of div was the document itself so its ok, but if you are handling with other divs you may try with offset, as you desire and needs :)